# Postgres index performance with duplicated data

Tags: database, postgresql

Having a table with the following columns:

```
users

 id     |  name   | city 
--------+---------+-----------
```

As many users are in the same city the same city could appear many times. By adding an index on it, do we get a performance benefit as values are repeated? or would it negatively affect performance?

Query I'm trying to run

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM users;
```

Comment: You may get a benefit with certain queries. What is the query?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT city FROM users;`

Comment: No index will help with this query as it has to scan the whole table. Try increasing `work_mem` for a speed boost.

Comment: understood. that helps a lot. Thanks. Should I update the question and want to add a formal answer so I can accept it?

Comment: If you want, but it is not necessary for me.

Answer (score 0):

The real solution here IMHO, is to normalize that table and create a new `City` table.  Like this:

```
User
    idUser: Primary key
    Name
    City_idCity  <-- foreign key to the City table

City
    idCity: Primary key
    Name
```

This way, there is no index to maintain (idCity is a primary key to table City anyway).  To get a list of existing cities, just

```
SELECT Name FROM City
```

Thus you do not need `DISTINCT` and avoid a full table scan.

You will also get the other benefits of normalized tables.

Ex. is the city of `New-York` the same as `New York`?  Or `NewYork`?  This ensures users will always have 1 single choice of city, and not create duplicates like they would do in a free text field.